# mongodb vertical scaling on EC2

Tags: mongodb

So I got my replica set up and running on an m3.large instance.

If I would like to **vertically scale** the replica set, will it be as easy as resizing the machine to a m3.2xlarge for example?

Should I change some mongodb configuration in order to let it use more memory or cpu?

Comment: MongoDB doesn't have any settings regulating its use of memory and CPU

Comment: I think you can just benefit this scale-up automatically in mongodb.

Comment: Mongodb doesn't manage memory, rather it leaves the memory management to OS. So, there is nothing you need to configure. Just resize the instance and it will start using resource if needed.